# HELP! New grapevine yellowing from bottom up w/ white fuzz & black tips

Tags: grape-vine

I bought this vine 3 weeks ago from a local nursery. Planted in new potting soil. I think I over watered in the beginning but have backed off to once a week since it’s been hot. The leaves have a white fuzz all over them. I’ve sprayed twice with copper anti fungal but it’s only looking worse. Now it’s yellowing from the bottom up and any new growth has dried and fallen off. The tiniest leaves are turning black at the tips. What should I do?[image]

[image]

Comment: If this is real time ( Sept. 12) ,depending where you are it may just be the end of the growing season..

Comment: Oh I hope so! That would be encouraging. Yep, took the picture 2 days ago, in Seattle.